# How do I write this force in terms of another variable?

Tags: geometry, taylor-expansion, physics, triangles, mathematical-physics

I have the tidal force, $\vec{F}=-GMm(\frac{\hat d}{d^2}-\frac{\hat d_0}{d_0^2})$ where:

[image]

How do I express the force in terms of $\theta$? I'm given that $\vec{r}=R(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$. I'm not sure how to fully eliminate $d$ and $d_0$. I could use the law of cosines, but I don't have an angle inside the triangle made by $r,d,$ and $d_0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Physically, the tidal force should take the revolution of the moon and the earth about their centre of mass into accounts.

Anyways, let's compute the expression.

\begin{align*}
  \mathbf{F} &= -GMm
  \left( \frac{\mathbf{d}}{d^3}-\frac{\mathbf{d}_0}{d_0^3} \right) \\
   &= -GMm
  \left(
    \frac{\mathbf{d}_0+\mathbf{r}}{|\mathbf{d}_0+\mathbf{r}|^3}-
    \frac{\mathbf{d}_0}{d_0^3}
  \right) \\
   &= -GMm
  \left[
    \frac{\mathbf{d}_0+\mathbf{r}}
         {(d_0^2+r^2-2\mathbf{d}_0 \cdot\mathbf{r})^{3/2}}-
    \frac{\mathbf{d}_0}{d_0^3}
  \right] \\
   & \approx -GMm
    \left[
      (\mathbf{d}_0+\mathbf{r})\left( \frac{1}{d_0^3}+
      \frac{3\mathbf{d}_0 \cdot\mathbf{r}}{d_0^5} \right)-
      \frac{\mathbf{d}_0}{d_0^3}
    \right] \\
   &= -GMm
    \left[
      \frac{3\mathbf{d}_0 \cdot\mathbf{r}}{d_0^5} \mathbf{d}_0+
      \left( \frac{1}{d_0^3}+
      \frac{3\mathbf{d}_0 \cdot\mathbf{r}}{d_0^5} \right)\mathbf{r}
    \right]
\end{align*}

Comment: It needs to be in terms of $\theta$ though.

Comment: Simple mathematics: $\mathbf{d}_0 \cdot\mathbf{r}=d_{0} r\cos (\pi-\theta)=-d_{0} r\cos \theta$

Comment: Oh wow this actually makes sense to me. Then I can also expand this in a Taylor series in $(r/d_0)$ right? Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, in principle but the higher order terms are getting more complicated.

Comment: Cool, thanks!!!

Comment: What do I do with the vectors $\hat d_0$ and $\hat r$ if I want to expand in a Taylor series?

Comment: Just expanding $$\frac{1}{(d_0^2+2d_0 r\cos \theta+r_0^2)^{3/2}}$$ and leaving $\mathbf{d}_0$ and $\mathbf{r}$

Answer (score 0):

You can use

$$
\mathbf{d}_0 + \mathbf{r} = \mathbf{d}
$$

To get rid of $\mathbf{d}$

$$
\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{d}_0) = - GM m \left(\frac{\mathbf{d}_0 + \mathbf{r}}{|\mathbf{d}_0 + \mathbf{r}|^3} + \frac{\mathbf{d}_0}{|\mathbf{d}_0|^3} \right)
$$

However, this is as far as you can get, the problem is that the position of the moon does not depend on the position of the mass $m$, say in another words, imagine you have a satellite orbiting Earth, and you know its location. Based on this information you cannot know where the moon is, so basically you cannot express $\mathbf{d}_0$ in terms of $\mathbf{r}$